# Different Image Block Sizes Using the GPU

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gpu

I wish to apply filter motion for certain number of iteration on different images, each image will be divided into different block size.

For example, if the image size is `1024x870`,how to divide this image into different block sizes `8x8`, `16x16`, `64x64`, etc. using MATLAB?

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: How to divide this image into different block sizes (8*8), (16*16), (64*64), etc. using matlab & jacket to run it under cuda

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5207960/1021231

Comment: So this is a question about image (really array) slicing in Matlab?

Comment: yes, after we slice the image into different block sizes we shall define the optimal block size to use in parallel processing on gpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect but I would do:

```
A=rand(128);
Apatch=im2col(A,[64 64],'distinct');
Apacth=gpuArray(Apatch);
```

Otherwise you can try (I am not sure it speeds up):

```
A=rand(128);
A=gpuArray(A);
Apatch=im2col(A,[64 64],'distinct');
Apacth=gpuArray(Apatch);
```